# How to use non-Part as - or similar to - ISelectionProvider?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, listener

I'm trying to get my custom `IOConsole` fire a `selectionChanged()` event, but as it is not a `ViewPart` or `EditorPart`, the registered `SelectionListeners` catch nothing, even when notified programatically.

Is this possible at all? Or is there another way to (programatically) notify a view of a change in my `IOConsole` so it can refresh one of its widgets? Oh, this should work for loosely coupled components as well, as none of the components really know of each other.

Comment: What *is* your `IOConsole` if not a workbench part?

Comment: Well, IOConsole doesn't inherit from WorkbenchPart for one: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fconsole%2FIOConsole.html ...

Answer (score 1):

If your console inherits from `org.eclipse.ui.console.IOConsole`, the `IOConsole` registers the text area (a `SourceViewer`) as a selection provider at the part site.

If you are certain that you want to *override* this behavior, you need to register your own `ISelectionProvider` at the part site. You can override `createPage` and change the selection provider after the page was created:

```java
class MyConsole extends IOConsole {
  @Override
  public IPageBookViewPage createPage( IConsoleView view ) {
    IPageBookViewPage consolePage = super.createPage( view );
    consolePage.getSite().setSelectionProvider( ... );  
    return consolePage;
  }
}
```

Note that overriding the IOConsole's selection provider this may result in an unintuitive behavior or interfere with assumptions that the `IOConsole` implementation makes.

Comment: @RüdigerHermann: Thanks. Unfortunately I do get an NPE when calling `consolePage.getSite()`...

Comment: Also, once I manage to get an existing site (would `view.getSite()` not work?), it might not accept a selection listener of type `ISelectionListener`, right? At least when trying to go via `view.getSite()`, I get a `ClassCastException` because the view site expects an object of type `PageBookView.SelectionProvider`. Complicated...